# C# UInt64 subtract issue

Tags: c#, uint64

Why subtraction with UInt64 data type sometimes error occurs. I reduce the number of seconds timespan with the result should be between 1 - 10, but the results of the system can be millions or even billions? Bugs ?

```
private bool isReplayRequest(string kode, string rTs)
{
    if (System.Runtime.Caching.MemoryCache.Default.Contains(kode))
    {
        return true;
    }
    
    DateTime eStart = new DateTime(1970, 01, 01, 0, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
    TimeSpan cTs = DateTime.UtcNow - eStart;
    var stotalSeconds = Convert.ToUInt64(cTs.TotalSeconds);
    var rTotalSeconds = Convert.ToUInt64(rTs);
    
    if ((stotalSeconds - rTotalSeconds) > maxSeconds)
    {
        return true;
    }
    
    .... etc ....
}
```

Issue on line (stotalSeconds - rTotalSeconds)

[image]

Comment: @Dai, question updated

Comment: send output error

Comment: i recommend you read [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) - better questions with the neccessary information attract more and better answers. but without _sample data_ and details about the error message, we could only blindly guess at your problem.

Comment: if `stotalSeconds < rTotalSeconds` the result would be negative and, when assigned to an `UInt64` that will result in a (often very large) positive value.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure this is the solution to your problem – just my first thought

By default the C# compiler does not check for arithmetic overflow

In Visual Studio you can enable this option in the properties of the project, build section, advanced settings

[image: Advances Build Settings]

Outside Visual Studio here are the compiler settings

`-checked`

or

```xml
<CheckForOverflowUnderflow>true</CheckForOverflowUnderflow>
```

Fabio

Comment: great, good information.